# AVPlayer doesn't play video from my parse

Tags: parse-platform, avplayer, parse-server, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play video from my parse server
I'm getting empty video player
And when i print the url i get the correct video url

```
let thevideo:PFFile! = (self.selectedmsg["file"] as! PFFile)
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: thevideo.url!)!
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

            let playercontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
            playercontroller.player = player

            self.presentViewController(playercontroller, animated: true) {

                player.play()
            }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, tried to search around for solution, but cannot, the only workable solution is save the file to device, and play it locally.

Comment: ah but that will be annoying, the issue with parse source? and they will fix it or not

Comment: as I guessed (and googled), it's caused by http headers when you try to load the file. And Parse is going to be shutdowned soon, they won't fix the issue, of course

Comment: so if parse shutdowned I cannot use parse-server in my local machine ?

Comment: Hey, I've solved my problem and now i can stream! I followed this tutorial hope it will works with you too: https://notehub.org/qukh9 Let me know if it worked. good luck